# Node Js, I am trying to stop duplicate items being add

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Node Js, i have a list builder that adds and shows the list however i am trying to change this so that duplicate items can't be added, at the moment this does not work.

```
const stdin = process.openStdin();
var items = [];
stdin.on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log(typeof chunk);
    var text = chunk.toString().trim();
    console.log(typeof text);
    if (text.indexOf('add ') === 0) {
        if(text.indexOf(items.value) === -1){
            console.log("There is all ready something there");
        }else{
            var space = text.indexOf(' ');
            var item = text.substring(space+1).trim();
            console.log('adding "'+item+'"');
            items.push(item);
        }
    }
    if (text.indexOf('list') === 0) {
        items.forEach(function(item, index) {
            console.log(index+'. '+item);
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `items.value` (which doesn't make sense, but...) in `text`, instead of looking for `text` in `items`:

```
if (text.indexOf('add ') === 0) {
  var space = text.indexOf(' ');   // NOTE: will always be 3, could just use that
  var item = text.substring(space+1).trim()

  if(items.indexOf(item) >= 0) {
    console.log("There is already something there")
  }
  else {
    items.push(item)
  }
}
```